# Visual Studio 2013 opens sln in text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ssis

Recently, my copy of Visual Studio started opening solution files in a text editor rather than loading the solution when I attempt to open solutions from the Source Control Explorer. If I use File -> Open -> Project/Solution or navigate to it in Explorer it opens normally.

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, with SSDT and SSDTBI installed. This started a few days ago, I noticed it first with SSIS solutions, so I tried a repair install of SSDTBI. That didn't help, so I tried a repair install of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and still no change.

Has anyone seen anything similar to this or have any suggestions about how I can get these solutions to open properly?

Thanks in advance for your help and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a repair install for the Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the defaults in visual studio?

If you right click on a sln in the explorer and click"open as" you should see what is configured.

Comment: In Windows Explorer, my default is still Visual Studio. In the source control explorer, I don't see an 'Open As' option at all

Comment: File-> Open File-> Open As (there should be a drop down next to the "open" button to select "Open As"...

Comment: When I open the solutions through the File -> Open dialog they open fine, the problem only occurs when I'm double clicking to open the solution in Source Control Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I had the same problem. I ran a repair for Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 without result.

What fixed it for me is installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.